# bootstrap col space before the labels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi how do i add space before my labels in this div? im using the bootstrap grid system. is it possible to do it without padding?

[image: screenshot]

```
<div class="module-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="event-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">Event:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="event-input">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="event-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">When:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">                                    
                                        <label class="event-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">Where:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="event-input">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="event-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">Cause:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="event-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">Preferred Skills:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="event-input">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="event-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">No. of Volunteers:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="description-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">Description:</label>
                                    </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="event-description">
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `container` class to your wrapper `div` or if you want a full width container you can use `container-fluid` class instead of `container`.

```
<div class="module-body container">
```

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

You are adding a row for each label and input group which is not a good practice.

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css);
```

```html
<div class="module-body container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="event-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">Event:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="event-input">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="event-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">When:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">                                    
                                        <label class="event-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">Where:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="event-input">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="event-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">Cause:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="event-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">Preferred Skills:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="event-input">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="event-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">No. of Volunteers:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="description-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">Description:</label>
                                    </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="event-description">
                                </div>
```

Comment: Adding "container" to "modal-body" will increase the width of modal-body itself leaving behind modal-header and modal-footer. Please recheck while applying "container" class to modal-body.

Comment: @Anonymous its a module not modal.

Comment: @Anonymous he can use the `container-fluid` class if he want a full width container.

Answer (score 0):

May Help structuring this way.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="row">
        <label class="event-label col-md-2" style="font-size:16px">
        Event:</label>
        <input type="text" class="event-input">
      </div>
</div>
```